# Laravel Eloquent - query joint tables contains a same col name

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I considered an issue when viewing data called from database using two related tables `users` and `roles` which have this structure:
[image]

- the `users.role` column contains an integer referring to the role record of `roles` table
- the `roles.name` column contains the role name i.e. (user / admin / editor)

in my controller I used the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries) to build my query as I need to show a table in blade that holds `users.name` , `users.email` and `roles.name` that related to user by the schema:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('roles', 'users.role', '=', 'roles.id')
        ->select('users.name', 'users.email', 'roles.name')
        ->get();
```

actually it works and dumping data, but the issue is the confusion of the two name alike cols `users.name` and `roles.name`. it dumping only the `roles.name` value like this sample record:

```
{"name":"user","email":"user@asd.com"},{"name":"user","email":"new@asd.com"},{"name":"user","email":"jaeden93@example.org"}
```

even when I tried to select all cols of `users` table like below:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('roles', 'users.role', '=', 'roles.id')
        ->select('users.*', 'roles.name')
        ->get();
```

the `users.name` col still not showing!

**Is** there a way to solve this issue without changing table's column titles ?

Comment: Is `->select('users.*', \DB::raw('roles.name as role_name'))` an option?

Comment: It works! but could you explain more in an answer maybe ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give an alias to the column, to avoid problems with the same name

Use this

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->join('roles', 'users.role', '=', 'roles.id')
    ->select('users.*', \DB::raw('roles.name as role_name'))
    ->get();
```

It's the same to do this in SQL

```
SELECT users.*, roles.name as role_name FROM ...
```

Comment: I've tried to beautify the code instead of typing  `DB::raw('roles.name as role_name')` I only typed `'roles.name as role_name'` and it also works fine